# fix the error : Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found

Tags: plugins, synchronization

When I create a new project in android studio, at first every thing is o.k and it runs on my mobile phone. But if I press the sync button then a terrible error(which I afraid of and hate it) is appeared: "Plugin with id 'com.android.application' not found". I search and read all answers related to this error and do every thing. But my problem is also remained.
Here is my build.gradle(module.app):

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
     compileSdkVersion 27
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.example.masood.pietest"
         minSdkVersion 16
         targetSdkVersion 27
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
         testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
 }

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}
```

and here is my build.gradle(project):

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha09'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
   }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Really, I don't know what I need to do...
Could anyone help me?

Comment: Seems like you've either commented or removed this line from the dependency on top-level gradle. `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'`

Answer (score 10):

After 3 days of trying to solve my above problem and searching and examining very solutions, I found that the problem raised from my "Android Plugin" version. So, if this problem occurs for every one especially for those who are new to android studio, before all, try to use from an appropriate version of "Android Plugin" which adjust with "Gradle version". To do this it's enough to look at this address: https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-plugin and https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin.html#updating-gradle.
For example, my Gradle version is "gradle-4.4" which requires at least to Plugin version "gradle:3.1.0". My Plugin version (when I had the above problem was gradle:3.1.0-alpha09) and the Sync process was encountering with error. So I change it to : "gradle:3.1.0" and now it works very well.

Notice:For checking your "gradle version" please go to the below directory on your application:

Gradle Scripts -> gradle-wrapper.properties

and for "plugin version" go to: Gradle Scripts -> build.gradle(Project:...) (NOT: build.gradle(app:...))

I hope this answer be useful for every one who have the same problem.